# Taming Garbage Collector CPU Usage

Tags: javascript, performance, garbage-collection

I am working on a little side project, a game of sorts that I built with D3, and I am currently trying optimize performance. Over time it really becomes a problem. Looking at the dev tools, it seems like the biggest issue is the Garbage Collector uses more and more CPU over time. It starts at around 20% and scales up to over 50% (at which point the game gets maybe a frame a second).

I have a couple of questions:

1. *What are general best practices to minimize Garbage Collector usage?*
2. *Does the steadily increasing CPU usage indicate any particular issue with my code?*

One tip I've already found is to save and reuse old objects rather than removing and recreating the, which I will work on next, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything else.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's kind of difficult to offer any meaningful advice other than to say: "reduce the number of objects that have to be garbage collected".

Comment: do some allocation profiling with whatever devtools you're using.